# How to get a dynamic attribute in loop

Tags: javascript, xml

I'm new to JS and I'm having troubles with handling an XML file.
So the JS script getting the XML file as an object and some values has it's own attributes, others not.
XML:

```
<Product>
<type>tank</type>
<armor>600</armor>
<armor_max type="limiter">800</armor_max>
<armor_price type="price">50</armor_price>
<top_speed>70</top_speed>
<fuel>20</fuel>
<fuel_price type="price">50</fuel_price>
<Gun type="array">
    <name>Gun</name>
    <info>125mm Cannon</info>
    <base_ammo>10</base_ammo>
    <max_ammo type="limiter">25</max_ammo>
    <ammo_price type="price">250</ammo_price>
</Gun>
```

(This is just a part of a big XML file.)
So as you can see I have some attributes with key "type". This file is being handled through JS script:

```
for (var key in data.xml){
   let abc = data.xml[key]['@attributes'];
   try {
       console.log(abc.type);
       } catch {

       }
```

Variable data.xml contains whole XML file. This code works properly for me, but I don't feel like this is a great solution. I've tried to use `console.log(data.xml[key]['@attributes']['type']);` but this make an error as object without attributes comes into the loop.

This `console.log(data.xml[key]);`writes down this for `data.xml[key]` where key = armor_price:

```
    {0: "50", @attributes: {…}}
0: "50"
@attributes: {type: "price"}
__proto__: Object
```

So, is there a better solution without using try..catch ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to make sure, that you are not trying to read property of an object which might be not defined on that object.

Depending of version of JS, you may use syntax like this:

```
for (var key in data){
  let abc = data[key]['@attributes'];
  console.log(abc && abc.type);
}
```

Should print `type` of `abc` if `abc` is an object (otherwise - it should return undefined, but without an error)

---

Recently syntactic sugar called `optional chaining` was also introduced to JavaScript (was present already in TypeScript), so with this you can do following:

```
for (var key in data){
  let abc = data[key]['@attributes'];
  console.log(abc?.type);
}
```

---

There are also other strategies to handle this, [here you can read more](https://css-tricks.com/%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8Bavoiding-those-dang-cannot-read-property-of-undefined-errors/)

Comment: Thank you so much. Also added a new check for undefined. `if (abc?.type !== undefined)`